# How to pass token address of one contract into another contract?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I have two contracts , one is company contract to register company and get its token and other is to make transaction using that token. so how can i use that token in second smart contract ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to pass the token contract address to the constructor of smart contract then you can use token in the smart contract like sample code below

```
contract TokenA {
{


contract B {
   TokenA token

   contructor(address _token) {
      token = TokenA(_token);
   }

}
```

Then you deployed the `TokenA` contract first then get out the contract address to pass to the constructor when deploying the contract `B`

Hope this help!